# How to detect which key is pressed when pointer wheel is changed using c# windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to detect which Key is pressed when pointer wheel changed event is fire.I use this function to detect the key

```
  private void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int keyValue = (int)e.Key;
    if ((keyValue >= 0x30 && keyValue <= 0x39) // numbers
     || (keyValue >= 0x41 && keyValue <= 0x5A) // letters
     || (keyValue >= 0x60 && keyValue <= 0x69)) // numpad
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

but unable to use this with pointer wheel changed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store information on which key got a down event and not an up one. You could probably also use `Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState()` or `GetAsyncKeyState()` for simplicity.